# How to concisely control a spriteNode's movement with swipes

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I am building a spriteKit game in Xcode 10.2.1 with swift 5, where the player has to reach the end of a large background (avoiding enemies, obstacles etc.) in order to complete the level. The camera is tied to the player spriteNode's position.x and the player can move the spriteNode in any direction with swipes.

I am using a cobbled together UIPanGestureRecognizer to enable this movement, and this seems to work reasonably well.

```
@objc func handlePan(recognizer: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {    
    let transformerX = 1024/self.view!.frame.size.width
    let transformerY = 768/self.view!.frame.size.height
    if recognizer.state == .began {
        lastSwipeBeginningPoint = recognizer.location(in: self.view)
    } else if (recognizer.state == .ended) {
        if scrolling { // this is controlls whether player can be moved - scrolling is set to true once introductory elements have run
            if playerDamage < 4 { //player cannot be controlled and falls off screen if it has 4 damage
                let velocity = recognizer.velocity(in: self.view)
                player.physicsBody?.applyImpulse(CGVector(dx: velocity.x * transformerX / 5.4, dy: velocity.y * transformerY * -1 / 5.4)) //-1 inverts y direction so it moves as expected
             }
         }
     }
}
```

This does allow movement around the level, but not in as precise and controlled a way as I would like. The player moves off at the set speed but any further swipes (to change direction/avoid obstacles) seem to multiply the speed and generally make it difficult to control accurately.
Is there a way of choking off the speed, so that it starts off at the set speed but then starts to lose momentum, or is there a better way altogether of controlling multi-direction movement?

Comment: You need to reset your velocity to 0

Comment: or directly set your velocity to the recognizer. Also, keep in mind that velocity is 150 points per meter.  Recognizer velocity is in points, physics velocity is in meters

Comment: Thank you. Could you explain how I can reset velocity to 0 or directly to the recognizer? I'm not sure how to go about it.

Comment: Figure it out on your own, not hard.  Start learning how to use documentation.

Comment: I checked the documentation before I asked  and found nothing relating to setting recognizer velocity. I tried to work it out myself but I’m not familiar enough with gesture recognizers- if I set velocity in the function to 0 then everything will multiply and divide out to 0 which doesn’t make sense. I couldn’t see a way of setting velocity directly to the recognizer, again I lack the experience which is why I was seeking help. If you are able to give me some guidance I would appreciate it. If not, thank you for your time and for pointing in the right direction, I’ll keep trying.

Comment: I found how to reset velocity to 0: lastSwipeBeginningPoint = CGPoint.zero and this seems a bit smoother. Still trying to find out how to directly set velocity to the recognizer as I'm curious to see if this will improve things further. Thanks again

Comment: no, you dont reset the velocity of the gesture, you reset the velocity of the sprite that is moving

Comment: I set the velocity to the recognizer by removing the transformerX and Y multiples and everything else apart from -1 on velocity.y. This was still too fast, so I  found a level that worked through trial and error:
player.physicsBody?.applyImpulse(CGVector(dx: velocity.x / 1.54, dy: velocity.y / -1.95 ))  I reset the sprite velocity (I think) by adding velocity = CGPoint.zero 
I also increased the physicsBody linearDampening: player.physicsBody?.linearDamping = 0.48
The net result is it is now working as I hoped it would, with fine control.
Thanks for the pointers, I got there in the end.

Comment: That is how you learn.  You just need to divide your velocity.x and .y by 150,  because a pan is done in screen points, but applyImpulse takes meters.  150pts = 1 meter

Comment: Ok. Am I right in thinking that applyImpulse is preferable to applyForce for a pan?

Comment: ApplyImpulse happens prior to the physics update, ApplyForce happens during the physics update.  Also, ApplyForce is in points, not meters (The documentation is wrong)

Comment: That would explain why when I tried applyForce I had to multiply rather than divide!